# Azure API management not listing all endpoints\methods

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway, azure-appservice

I created an .NET Core based rest API. Then I containerized the application and hosted it over Azure App Service. I was able to see various controller and endpoints using Swagger. I was able to make request and I was able to receive response.

[image]

Then I created an Azure API management resource and added this App service as API. After the deployment, all the methods are empty. I do not see any endpoints. **What can I do to fix this issue ?**

[image]

I added the API to Azure API management by following steps:

1. Under API Management > APIs
2. - Add API
3. Select app Service
4. In the pop-up browse for App Service & provide display name, name, API URL suffix and click Create.

[image]

Comment: Can you share how you added the app service?

Comment: I believe you still need to import the swagger file.  What you shared, apim doesn’t know where your file/page is

Answer (score 1):

You have to install swashbuckle to your app service application so your app service returns a configuration endpoint where apim can find the open api spec or the swagger definition of your Apis and use it to import the Apis to apim

Assuming you use .Net Core, you have to install these packages
[image]

and insert the below line of code in your startup.cs (The Configure Method)

```
    app.UseSwagger(options =>
    {
        options.SerializeAsV2 = true; // this is optional to control the swagger version
    });

    app.UseSwaggerUI(); //optional
```

[image]